# Copy-pasted large folder but didn't have enough space. Cancelled the paste, but storage was taken up anyways

Tags: laptop, storage

I don't know if specifics of the folder are needed, but I had a large folder already downloaded on my C: drive. I copy and pasted it onto my desktop but there wasn't enough space for the download to finish so I cancelled the paste. After looking at my storage I saw that it was taken up even though I cancelled the paste. Is there a way I can find this partially downloaded folder, or undo this to get my storage back?

Comment: If it contained multiple files, some may already have been copied already. Are you sure there’s nothing in the target location?

Answer (score 0):

There are various Disk Space visualization tools, such as TreeSize or WizTree that can show you a visual representation of your disk and the folders and files using up the space on it.

You should start with Windows' own Disk Cleanup because it's there, and it's simple to use.

Next, you should check the destination folder. If the file was partially copied, the parts that copied before you canceled the copy will still be there.